# how to stop "cannot stop" builds on TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, build-agent

I get "cannot stop" status once in a while after trying to stop builds on TeamCity. I would expect that killing my build process on build agent would do the trick, but it doesn't work. Stopping TeamCity agent process on the build machine doesn't help either. Restarting build agent (i.e. computer) does the trick, but it takes plus 2-3min after the machine has started. It looks like TeamCity server itself thinks that my build is still running.

Is there a better way to stop those builds? Or maybe there is some info somewhere that could explain this logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see/vote for http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/TW-3154 and related requests

Comment: Any workaround (even low-level) without machine reboot will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just restart the TeamCity WebServer windows service.
You shouldn't need to restart your whole machine.

Comment: I restarted the 'TeamCity Build Agent Service' instead, and the build immediately died.

Comment: I had to kill several other processes (Testrunners, ...) and then it died and I could restart the  'TeamCity Build Agent Service'.